# Is it necessary to create all views in storyboard in the beginning?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS and have recently finished some classes.

Now, I'm onto my first app with Swift. I wanted to know:

> Is it necessary to define all views/screens in the storyboard right in
>   the beginning, with proper navigation controllers?
>
> What is better, define all in the beginning or keep adding as need
>   arises in the future?

Comment: Unless you can anticipate all the views and screens that you need, I think its wiser to keep adding as a go. In a perfect world, yeah you should plan everything, so you could add all the views in the beginning for sake of visualisation and organisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep adding as needed.

You'll always be finding or coming up with new features, and at times you'll need to insert view controllers between other view controllers (adding an extra step, for example).

Within view controllers, you'll also find the need to put items into containers.  That's where clicking the item/s (selecting them), and going to the menu, selecting "Editor" and then "Embed In" comes in really handy.  For example, you may want to put a series of items into a scrollview *after* you've already laid them out properly, because they don't display properly on an iPhone (and you had done all of your testing in Simulator on an iPad first).

Comment: This also works with View Controllers and adding in Navigation Controllers after the fact, which I had to do on my last project...

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, you can create all views programmatically without using a storyboard at all. Its's just your choice what works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use storyboards for your UI (and navigation), use .xibs (only UI) or create everything programmatically. Each of these has its pros and cons. Also you can mix and match all these. For example have a storyboard, some views with .xibs and some views created programmatically all in the same project. You just have to choose what fits best your needs.

You don't have to create everything in the storyboard right in the beginning. Create only the views you need to start coding and then add more views as you progress your app development.

Comment: And of course, you can have multiple storyboards. You can also load individual scenes from storyboards programmatically whenever needed.